# How to print Django queryset in Tabular form in python3 manage.py shell

Tags: django, django-models, django-shell

Is there a way or package to print Django queryset in Tabular form in python3 manage.py shell

The queryset prints like

[image: this]

But I want it to be printed like

[image: this]

Comment: maybe use django-pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django doesn't have this feature, but it would be easy to create a function using [tabulate](https://github.com/astanin/python-tabulate)

```
from tabulate import tabulate

def output_table(queryset, limit=50):
    headers = [x.name for x in queryset.model._meta.fields]
    rows = queryset.values_list(*headers)
    if limit is not None:
        rows = rows[:limit]
    print(tabulate(rows, headers))
```

Comment: Thanks. It's doing wonders but isn't there any package which does this out of box without writing custom code?

Comment: There might be packages that do something like this but I don’t know of any.